# How to calculate the accuracy of an address?

Tags: python, street-address

I have a list of (house/apartment) addresses, along with a list of that house/apartment's price.
I then stick it into the Zillow API and it gives me back the address (that Zillow predicts given the address that I give it) and the Zestimate of that house.

Sometimes, the Zillow API is not completely accurate, and gives me back the wrong apartment number, or the entire apartment instead of just one apartment. Since Zillow is predicting the wrong building, the Zestimate is completely off.

I don't need to fix it, but want to be able to calculate some accuracy score of the house address that I get back from Zillow. Are there any APIs that will give me an accuracy score?

(For example, an API similar to SmartyStreets (but preferably free) that takes in the expected price of the address and the Zestimate that Zillow gives back)

I would implement it as a simple function that takes the given/original address, the given/original home price, Zillow's estimation of the the Zestimate.

```
measure_accuracy(orig_add, orig_price, zillow_add, zillow_est) {
...
}
```

Comment: show us some code

Comment: Updated question!